# Drawing line from previous frame to current frame

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

I am using optical flow to understand motion between 2 consequetive frames of a video. But i want to know how to draw a line from initial point in one frame to updated point of next frame. I am not sure about how to draw a line from one image to another and keep both frames updating. I was thinking about using cv2.hconcat. can anyone please help?

Comment: There are built-in functions to perform this. Please have a look into [this blog](https://learnopencv.com/optical-flow-in-opencv/). Also `cv2.hconcat` is not the right function to use. For starters, store the point from the first frame in a variable. On the next frame, draw line using `cv2.line` from the first point stored in the variable and the new point on the current frame

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: asked again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71813743/drawing-line-from-one-video-to-another

Comment: If t frame and t+1 frame are kept side by side using cv2.hconcat , is it posibble to draw line joining initial coordinate of t frame to updated coordinate of t+1 frame. Basically to draw the line over the 2 images kept side by side